# How to mask specific user in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
ALTER TABLE tblExample
    ALTER COLUMN xxx ADD MASKED WITH(FUNCTION='default()')
```

This makes masked for every user except admin.

```
GRANT/DENY UNMASK TO USERONE
```

I want to mask for only 1 user. I don't want to mask all users -> drop masks for all users except that specific one

Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Security wise this is not a good practice at all...however, if you want all current&future db users to be able to unmask and a single user not to, then you could grant unmask to public and deny it to the "pooruser" (deny supersedes grant)

```
grant unmask to public;
deny unmask to pooruser;
```